# assistance on displaying data in colunm PHP MySQL (Modified Preorder Tree Trasversal)

Tags: php, mysql, adjacency-list-model, modified-preorder-tree-t

Hello I'm trying to get a multicolumn display (if it can be called so) with the code below here is the result: [image]
. Someone can see why These leaves are broken? or tell me please which is better: a catagory table linked to a subcatery one, or an adjacency model list.

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  node.idCat_ad ,node.".$cat_name.",(COUNT(parent.".$cat_name.") - 1) AS depth 
                       FROM cat_ad AS node 
                       CROSS JOIN cat_ad AS parent 
                       WHERE node.left_node BETWEEN parent.left_node AND parent.right_node
                       GROUP BY node.idCat_ad
                       ORDER BY node.left_node"); 

$stmt->execute();
$treeArray = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>

<div class="column_in_categories">
<div class="menucategories"><ul>

<?php
$x = 0; //counter
$num_cols = 3; //3 colums
$num_rows = count($resTree); //num columns

$result = ''; 

$newArray =array_slice($resTree,1); //removing the root tree

foreach ($newArray as $currNode) { 

   if ($currNode['depth'] ==1) { //no links in root

     $result .= '<li class="header '.$classSprites.'">' . $currNode[$cat_name] . '</li>';

  } else{ //if child, we put a link

   $result .= '<li class="subcat"><a href="#">' . $currNode[$cat_name] . '</a></li>';
  }

 $x++; // incrementing da counter

 if ($x == ceil($num_rows / $num_cols)) { //if a colunm, we clause it and begin another

   $result .= '</ul></div> <div class="menucategories"><ul><li style="display:none;">&nbsp;</li>';
   $x=0; //
  }

} 
$result .="</ul></div>";
print $result;
```

Serialized version [link text](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1TEEJaflFmAQZ9Hb7iCt180oW2ZlrLH9frkTxzc8Wtro&hl=en&authkey=CKavtZAP)

Comment: Any chance you can provide a serialized version of `$resTree`, so I can try and sandpit a solution for this?

Comment: @Lucanos, I upload the serialized version. Find it below the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
foreach ($newArray as $currNode) { 

   if ($currNode['depth'] ==1) { //no links in root

     $result .= '<li class="header '.$classSprites.'">' . $currNode[$cat_name] . '</li>';

  } else{ //if child, we put a link

   $result .= '<li class="subcat"><a href="#">' . $currNode[$cat_name] . '</a></li>';
  }

 $x++; // incrementing da counter

 if ($x == ceil($num_rows / $num_cols)) { //if a colunm, we clause it and begin another

   $result .= '</ul></div> <div class="menucategories"><ul><li style="display:none;">&nbsp;</li>';
   $x=0; //
  }

}
```

by

```
foreach ($newArray as $currNode) { 

 $x++; // incrementing da counter

 if ($x >= ceil($num_rows / $num_cols) and $currNode['depth'] ==1) { //if a colunm, we clause it and begin another

   $result .= '</ul></div> <div class="menucategories"><ul><li style="display:none;">&nbsp;</li>';
   $x=0; //
  }

   if ($currNode['depth'] ==1) { //no links in root

     $result .= '<li class="header '.$classSprites.'">' . $currNode[$cat_name] . '</li>';

  } else{ //if child, we put a link

   $result .= '<li class="subcat"><a href="#">' . $currNode[$cat_name] . '</a></li>';
  }

}
```

This will start new columns only when new headlines start.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Effectively, new colunms start only after new headlines. Now a new problem occurs: if $num_cols is set to 3, I get 2 columns, if it iquals to [1 ∞]-{3} :), I get one column.